# The best way to check is mouse move outside window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have to check 4 sides if I want to limit mouse in window to take action like

```
$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
  if (e.pageX > 10 && e.pageX<$(window).width-10 && e.pageY< $(window).height()-10&& e.pageY >10){
//are there any better way?
}

});
```

Comment: Is that a statement or a question? And if you move the mouse outside the window, the function no longer fires ?

Comment: Write a function and forget about it? If this works for you, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is probably to hook into the `mouseout` event. Try it out with `document.body` or similar.

Comment: Tested? I'm interested in the results of this test.

Comment: yeah mouseout, i forgot about it, stupid me always using clumsy ways